# Count number of row in a specific datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset contains two tables. The first one contains the column named "Equipment availability"
The second one is not. I want to count the number of rows in the first table but my code doesn't work. It counts the total number of two tables?

```
Private Sub GetNumber(ByVal dataSet As DataSet)
    Dim table As DataTable
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim column As DataColumn
    Dim count_value As Long = 0
    Dim count_row As Long = 0
    For Each table In dataSet.Tables
        For Each column In table.Columns
            If column.ColumnName = "Equipment availability" Then
                count_row += table.Rows.Count
                For Each row In table.Rows
                    If Not IsDBNull(row(column)) AndAlso row(column) = 1 Then
                        count_value += 1
                    End If
                Next row
            End If
        Next column
    Next table
    TextBox1.Text = count_value
    TextBox2.Text = count_row
```

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. If you want to know how many rows are in a `DataTable` then get the `Count` property of its `Rows` collection, e.g. `Dim rowCount = myDataTable.Rows.Count`.

Comment: If what you actually want is the number of rows that match particular criteria then you can call the `Select` method of the `DataTable`.  It returns a `DataRow` array, so you can get the `Length` of that.

Comment: Name your tables when you add them to the dataset.  Then you can just reference the table without guessing which one you are dealing with.

Comment: My database is exported from another software. So I have to handle this. Basically, I have numerous tables in dataSet( exactly 269 tables). And just few tables have the column name "Equipment availability". I want to count the total rows in those tables,  and the total value in column "Equipment availability" having value =1. So I need loop.

Comment: I try but it doesn't work?